# MYSQL Query - Find rows where multiple ID match, but states are different

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 databases, 1 with order number (orders)

```
| id | reference | ....
   1    12345678   ....
   2    12345679   ....
```

and another with order_state_history (order_history)

```
| id | id_order | order_state | ....
   1      1           3
   1      1           7
   1      1           5
   2      1           3
   2      1           7
   2      1           1
```

And I need to get all order references that have had 1 specific order_state in the order_history, but NEVER had some other states

For example, all order that have had state **3 and 7**, but **never had state 5**. (only should return the reference from order id 2)

I tried some random simple queries like, but without any luck, if someone can help me with this it would be really much appreciated.

[Here where my attempts, I don't have much experience with SQL]

```
SELECT 
    p.id_order,
    p.reference,
    o.id_order_state AS "state_a",
    b.id_order_state AS "state_b"
FROM
    order_history o
JOIN  orders p 
ON o.id_order = p.id_order
JOIN order_history AS b
ON p.id_order = b.id_order
WHERE o.id_order_state = 76 AND b.id_order_state = 4 AND b.id_order_state NOT IN (26,20,22,23)
```

Thank for your time!

Comment: "*I tried some random simple queries like, but without any luck...*" Please share these attempts, along with a short explanation *why* they didn't meet your requirements. This will greatly help the community to ensure that the solutions proposed don't duplicate the efforts you've already made, and can be helpful for you to have your errors/misunderstandings pointed out and explained.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I have added some SQL attempts, and I will try to improve the question once I have some time, sorry about that !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is rather poorly phrased but you can use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select order_id
from order_state
group by order_id
having sum(state = 3) > 0 and
       sum(state = 7) > 0 and
       sum(state = 5) = 0;
```